# implode explode data in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select

I am using multiple select from a select drop down and I want to store it in database.

I have heard about implode explode, but I have no idea how to use them. Please give me an idea how to implode and explode in codeigniter.

My HTML form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Please Select Proof Of ID Deposit
    </label>
    <select multiple="" name="oids" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control">
        <optgroup>
            <option value="Passport">Passport</option>
            <option value="National ID Card">National ID Card</option>
            <option value="Driving Licence">Driving Licence</option>
            <option value="Univesity ID">Univesity ID</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
public function customer_insert(){
    $data = array(
        'id'=>$this->input->post('up_id'),
        'Other_id'=>$this->input->post('oids') //here I want to implode my values
    )
    $this->db->insert('customer', $data);
}
```

View file:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>ID</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Other ID</td></tr>
    </thead>
<?php foreach ($query as $customer){?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $customer->id?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><?php echo $customer->Other_id?></td></tr> // I want to show my imploded value here. 
<?php}?>
</table>
```

Comment: You should store the ID - OID combinations in a separate table. That way you can search and filter in the future.

Comment: ok i can save that but my main problem is i want to save multiple value in one column in my database and show them in view... how can i achieve that??

Answer (score 3):

Firstly within your **HTML FORM** you need to change the `name` attr value with an array unless it will not produce an array of selected values

```
<select multiple="" name="oids" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control">
```

must be like

```
<select multiple="" name="oids[]" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control">
```

And within your **controller function**

```
public function customer_insert() {

    $oidVal = implode(",", $this->input->post('oids'));// Converted array into comma separated value using implode

    $data = array(
        'id'=> $this->input->post('up_id'),
        'Other_id'=> $oidVal
    )
    $this->db->insert('customer', $data);
}
```

and within your **View File**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>ID</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Other ID</td></tr>
    </thead>
<?php foreach ($query as $key => $value) { ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $value['id']; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><?php echo explode(',',$value['Other_id']);?></td></tr> // exploded value
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Then accept it as an answer so this must be considered as closed issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [implode](http://php.net/implode) function to join array elements with a string and [explode](http://php.net/explode) function to split a string by string. In this case you can use them like this.

```
public function customer_insert() {
    // Convert array to comma separated value 
    $oidString = implode(",", $this->input->post('oids'));
    $data = array(
        'id'=> $this->input->post('up_id'),
        'Other_id'=> $oidString //here I want to implode my values
    )
    $this->db->insert('customer', $data);
}
```

If you want to get back array from comma separated value, you can use `explode`.

```
// Convert comma separated value to array
$otherId = explode(",", $customer->Other_id);
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function insert()
 {
//Insert second stage details for employer into database.
$Specilized_category = $this->input->post('spec_cat');
$data=array(
'Specilized_category'=>json_encode(implode(",", $Specilized_category)),
 );
$this->db->insert('tbl_employer', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to change the name attr value with an array unless it will not produce an array of selected values

```
<div class="col-xxl-3 col-md-3">
  <label for="validationCustom03" class="form-label">Supplier  *</label>
  <select class="form-control supplier_select" name="supplier[]" multiple="multiple" required>
    <?php 
      $supplier_array_data=explode(",", $user_data->supplier);
      foreach($supplier_data as $supplier) {
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $supplier->supplier_id;?>" ><?php echo $supplier->supplier_name;?></option>
   <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Supplier is required.
  </div>
</div>

<?php
  //Controller function
  public function supplier ()
  {
    //implode
    $supplier = implode(",", $this->input->post('supplier'));
    print_r($supplier);
 
    //Explode
    $explode_supplier =explode(",", $supplier);
    print_r($explode_supplier);
  }
?>
```